# Root of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots

I need help to answer the question b) of the following problem:

Let $F$ be a field not of caracteristic 2 and consider the field of fraction $F(u)$ in the variable $u$.

> a) Show that $f(x)=x^2+u^2-1$ is irreductible in $F(u)[x]$.

Let $v$ be a root of $f$ and  define $t=(1-v)/u$.

> b) Show that $F(u,v)=F(t)$

Hint: compute $1+t^2$

This is what i tried to do:

$ 1+t^2=(u^2+(1-v)^2)/u^2=(u^2+1+v^2-2v)/u^2=(2-2v)/u^2=2(1-v)/u^2=2t/u $

But I don't know how to use that to get the answer.

Comment: You have shown that $2t/u \in F(t)$. What does that imply about $u$?

Comment: that implies $u\in F$?

Comment: i am not able to answer can you please help me more? thanks

Comment: I think you may need to revisit the definitions of $F(t)$ and $F(u,v)$ at this point. The issue seems to be that you don't 100% understand the problem.

Comment: You proved that $2t/u\in F(t)$, since $F(t)$ is a field, $u\in F(t)$, with your other equations you can conclude that $v\in F(t)$.

Comment: and what piece of elementary mathematics does the b) recapitulate?  Does that mean that a field of fraction of one variable is always equal to a fileld of fraction of two variables?

Comment: It means that you can not only parametrize (part of) the circle via the sine but also via the tangent of the half angle.